# How do I preserve GIF animation with the image field and image styles?

Tags: media

Currently, when I upload animated GIFs to image fields, image styles breaks the animation as part of the crop/resize sequence.

I'd love to be able to preserve animation while also taking advantage of image styles. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, there already is some discussion:

- Pure PHP with imageMagick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation
- Drupal discussion - https://drupal.org/node/1115658
- Issue for ImageMagick module with patch - https://drupal.org/node/1802534 - several users claim that it is working.